Why are kinematic tangent vectors continuous in the convenient vector space topology?
In the following excerpt from Michor's The Convenient Setting of Global Analysis, why is $X_a$ continuous in the topology of $E$? $\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}$ No explanation is given in the text.

28.1. The tangent spaces of a convenient vector space $E$. Let $a ∈ E$. A kinematic tangent vector with foot point a is simply a pair $(a, X)$ with $X ∈ E$. Let $T_aE = E$ be the space of all kinematic tangent vectors with foot point $a$. It consists of all derivatives $c'$ at $0$ of smooth curves $c : \RR → E$ with $c(0) = a$,
which explains the choice of the name kinematic.
For each open neighborhood $U$ of $a$ in $E$ $(a, X)$ induces a linear mapping $X_a : C^∞(U, \RR) → \RR$ by $X_a(f) := df(a)(X)$, which is continuous for the convenient vector space topology on $C^∞(U, \RR)$ and satisfies $X_a(f · g) = Xa(f)· g(a) +f(a)· Xa(g)$, so it is a continuous derivation over $\text{ev}_a$. The value $X_a(f)$ depends only on the germ of $f$ at $a$.


$X_a$ is not "continuous in the topology of $E$", It is not a mapping on $E$ at all. It is a function on $C^\infty(U, \Bbb R)$, and therefore it is the topology on $C^\infty(U, \Bbb R)$ and on its codomain $\Bbb R$ that determine whether or not it is continuous. And to determine that, one would need to know what the "convenient topology" on $C^\infty(U, \Bbb R)$ is. And since I do not have that book, and all I can find by searching is other books I do not have access to, I cannot say.
